Implement Autocomplete Input with Azure Maps
I am currently working on implementing an autocomplete input field using Azure Maps. I have previously implemented similar functionality with Google Maps and Bing Maps, following this migration documentation.
For Google Maps and Bing Maps, the process was straightforward, and I could follow the available documentation to achieve the desired autocomplete functionality https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/bingmaps/getting-started/google-maps-to-bing-maps-migration-guide/google-maps-to-bing-maps-migration-guide.
Autosuggest in Bing Maps However, when trying to do the same with Azure Maps, I have encountered some difficulties.
So far, I have only found a custom implementation using Kendo UI, but I am looking for a more direct approach using Azure Maps services. Does Azure Maps provide a built-in autocomplete feature similar to Google Maps and Bing Maps? If so, could you provide an example or point me to the relevant documentation?
Any guidance or example code snippets would be greatly appreciated!
Actual code with KendoUI:
HTML
<html>
    <head>
    </head>
    <body>
        <input type="text" id="queryText" style="width: 100%;" />
        <p></p>
        <div id="mapControl" style="position: relative;width:100%;min-width:290px;height:500px;"></div>

        <script id="autoCompleteItemTemplate" type="x-kendo-template">
            # var suggestionLabel = address.freeformAddress; #
            # if (poi && poi.name) { #
            #   suggestionLabel = poi.name + ' - (' + suggestionLabel + ')'; # 
            # } #
            <span>#:suggestionLabel#</span>
        </script>
    </body>
</html>

JS
let map;
let azureSearchDataSource;
let azureMapDataSource;
const mapCenter = [-73.985130, 40.758896]
const defaultZoom = 15;

function initializeMap() {
    map = new atlas.Map('mapControl', {
        center: mapCenter,
        zoom: defaultZoom,
        authOptions: {
            authType: "subscriptionKey",
            subscriptionKey: azureKey
        }
    });

    map.events.add('ready', function () {
        azureMapDataSource = new atlas.source.DataSource();
        map.sources.add(azureMapDataSource);
        map.layers.add(new atlas.layer.SymbolLayer(azureMapDataSource));
        azureMapDataSource.add(new atlas.data.Point(mapCenter));
    })
}

$(() => {

    azureSearchDataSource = new kendo.data.DataSource({
        serverFiltering: true,
        transport: {
            read: {
                url: "https://atlas.microsoft.com/search/poi/json?typeahead=true&api-version=1&view=Auto&language=en-US&countrySet=US&subscription-key=" + azureKey,
                type: "get",
                dataType: "json",
                data: function() {
                    var center = map.getCamera().center;
                    var searchTerm = $("#queryText").data("kendoAutoComplete").value();
                    return {
                        lon: center[0],
                        lat: center[1],
                        query: searchTerm
                    }
                }
            }
        },
        schema: {
            type: "json",
            data: function(response) {
                return response.results;
            },
            model: {
               id: "id"
            }
        }
    })

    $('#queryText').kendoAutoComplete({
        minLength: 3,
        placeholder: "Select a venue",
        dataValueField: "id",
        dataTextField: "poi.name",
        template: $('#autoCompleteItemTemplate').html(),
        dataSource: azureSearchDataSource,
        select: function (e) {
            var item = e.dataItem;
            console.log(item.poi.name);
            
            map.setCamera({
                center: [item.position.lon, item.position.lat],
                zoom: defaultZoom});
            azureMapDataSource.add(new atlas.data.Point([item.position.lon, item.position.lat]));
        }
    });
    initializeMap();

});

What I've tried:
Searching through the Azure Maps documentation
Implementing a custom solution with Kendo UI
What I'm looking for:
A way to implement autocomplete functionality directly with Azure Maps
Example code or documentation references
Thank you in advance for your help!

Azure Maps does not have a built in UI for autocomplete at this time. There are a lot of different frameworks people use these days and often have a lot of different customization requirements. Many of these frameworks have UI components for autocomplete scenarios (often several to choose from).
